# Shell script, repeatedly run until success

Tags: bash, cron

I have a routine where i need to check if two files are uploaded to a specific folder. I'm trying to write a script to automate this for me and just report to slack / mail / whatever.

I need to check if file1 has been uploaded every day. file2 is supposed to be uploaded on each monday, so i need to check on mondays. But if it hasn't been uploaded i need to check the next day and so forth.

I have created a script to check and report this running every day as a cronjob, but after file2 is uploaded, it reports success every time it runs the rest of the week, is there a way to "stop running a block of code" if the script has reported success once?

Here is the simple script without reporting code:

```
#!/bin/zsh

if [ -f "path/to/file1" ]
then
    # report ok
else
    # report warning
fi

if [ -r "path/to/file2" ]
then
    # report ok
else
    # report warning
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to handle the specific issue that you are dealing with is not what you are asking for, but more simply, break up the script into two, the check-every-day, and check-every-monday one.

Thus your check-every-monday script will not be interfering with the check-every-day one, which seems to be the only problem you are trying to solve. Otherwise, your question is not clear enough for people to understand.